# Error al instanciar ViewModelProviders

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-viewmodel, android-room

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio que estoy realizando en Android. Estoy tratando de implementar *Room + LiveData y ViewMode*. Ya tengo toda la estructura de mi proyecto hecha, pero al momento de iniciar la aplicación, el fragmento que se supone me debe cargar la lista de mis registros, que tengo guardados en Room, me da el siguiente error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class
>   com.example.pokemonmastergame.NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel
>           at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:208)

He estado leyendo y algunos post comentaban que tenia que definir mi constructor como publico, pero el problema es que ya esta así. No se que es lo que esta fallando, este es mi método donde ejecuto mi `ViewModelProviders`:

```
private void lanzarViewModel() {
        nuevoPokemonDialogViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel.class);
        nuevoPokemonDialogViewModel.getAllPokemon().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<PokemonEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<PokemonEntity> pokemonEntities) {
                myPokemonListRecyclerViewAdapter2.setNuevosPokemon(pokemonEntities);
            }
        });
    }
```

Y esta es la clase que obtengo en el `ViewModelProviders`:

```
public class NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private LiveData<List<PokemonEntity>> allPokemon;
    private PokemonRespository pokemonRespository;

    public NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel(Application application){
        super(application);

        pokemonRespository = new PokemonRespository(application);
        allPokemon = pokemonRespository.getAll();
    }

    //El fragmento que necesita recibir la nueva lista de datos
    public LiveData<List<PokemonEntity>> getAllPokemon(){ return allPokemon; }
    //El fragmento que inserte una nueva nota, debera comunicarlo a este ViewModel
    public void insertarPokemon(PokemonEntity nuevopokemonEntity){ pokemonRespository.insert(nuevopokemonEntity);}

}
```

No entiendo porque me esta dando ese error

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre solucionarlo, el error me daba porque me faltaba agregar estas lineas en mi gradle:

> annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.3"
>
> androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.3"

Comment: es un poco raro lo que comentas, estas dependencias son para Room.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente la forma para instancia ViewModel es obsoleta, debe ser:

```
//nuevoPokemonDialogViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel.class);
 nuevoPokemonDialogViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel.class);
```

ahora el problema es causado porque la clase que debe extender `NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel` debe ser `ViewModel`:

```
//public class NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
public class NuevoPokemonDialogViewModel extends ViewModel {
```

no olvidar la dependencia:

```
   implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```